# Scala collection one-to-one mapping?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Pardon me if it's simple, but what is the most efficient way to do the following in scala:

Say I have two collections A and B with exactly same number of elements. For example,

```
A = {objectA1, objectA2, .... objectAN} 
B = {objectB1, objectB2, .... objectBN}
```

I would like to get `{{objectA1, objectB1}, {objectA2, objectB2}, ... {objectAN, objectBN}}`. Note that these collections might be very large.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Zip them:

```
A zip B
```

Example:

```
scala> val a = Seq(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
a: Seq[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> val b = Seq('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')
b: Seq[Char] = List(a, b, c, d, e)

scala> a zip b
res5: Seq[(Int, Char)] = List((1,a), (2,b), (3,c), (4,d), (5,e))
```

If `A` and `B` are iterators, this will create an iterator of pairs as well.

Comment: Zipping is the easiest way. If you need the elements to be sequences and not tuples (like your question suggests), you could do (A zip B).map{(a,b)=>List(a,b)}

Comment: Thanks a lot Tomasz and Heinzi!

Answer (score 9):

Some additions to @Tomasz answer: If collections are very large it is inefficient to use `a zip b` because it will create a complete intermediate collection. There is an alternative:

```
scala> (a,b).zipped
res15: scala.runtime.Tuple2Zipped[Int,Seq[Int],Char,Seq[Char]] = scala.runtime.Tuple2Zipped@71060c3e

scala> (a,b,b).zipped // works also for Tuple3
res16: scala.runtime.Tuple3Zipped[Int,Seq[Int],Char,Seq[Char],Char,Seq[Char]] = scala.runtime.Tuple3Zipped@30b688e1
```

Internally, [Tuple2Zipped](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Tuple2%24Zipped) and [Tuple3Zipped](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Tuple3%24Zipped) use iterators. This makes it more efficient when you want to transform the zippers.